# Magento 2: Product URL Suffix

Tags: magento2, product, url

How do I remove the .html suffix from the product pages?

Comment: From *just* the product pages?

Comment: The .html suffix only seems to appear on the product pages. The CMS pages don't show .html, nor does the home page.

Comment: Categories should also show .html - would you like to remove it or change it?

Comment: Ahhh yes, you're correct, the category page has it too. I'd prefer a forward slash in its place.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Open your admin panel navigate on **Stores->configuration->Catalog** 
click on **Search Engine Optimization** tab

Here you can remove

**Product URL Suffix** =

**Category URL Suffix** =

[image]

Make these fields **blank** (remove .html from both fields) **save the config** and **reindex** and clear cache of your store.
it's done!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, when I removed the .html, I received a 404 on all product and category pages?

Comment: Did you reindex and clear cache ??

Comment: Yes, but it still shows 404  :-/

Comment: This is the right way for achieve this functionality. Delete var/generation  folder retry and also see log files for any errors

Comment: Okay, thank you. Where are the log files located?

Comment: look at yourMagentoRootDIr/var

Comment: It worked. I have to empty / delete the var folders. Thank you!

Comment: @Arunendra, I have posted similar question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/171759/magento-2-html-html-issue-after-update-from-catalog-configuration) Could you please check it once?

Comment: What about the indexed content in search engines?

Comment: @Arunendra, the solution is not working for me. I am using Magento 2.1.7. I am getting **`Error filtering template: Element with ID 'widget.products.list.pager' already exists.
`** error. Please help.

Comment: It should be noted that since a [commit](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/f70f1b2826280bbe18a73a66dc2ff5f70c8d2d1b#diff-eb1d8c6c0059c0e71a5cbdc544a4558fR144) on May 14, 2019, setting those configs to empty from the admin will throw errors after trying to access the product or category pages, because the admin will save `NULL` instead of an empty string, and that commit expects a string. Setting to an empty string directly in the DB and clearing cache fixes this. [Read more about this issue.](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29442)

Answer (score 6):

You can just remove .html suffix from your admin panel.

Go to AdminPanel,

> Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog

Go to **`Search Engine Optimization`** Section,

**Unset value for textfield inside Product URL Suffix**

Same as you can do it for category url suffix below another field is `Catogory Url Suffix`.

If you can do any text with this field like .php then its display suffix as .php in your link.

Remove var folder and run commnad **`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`**

Comment: This works well in Magento 2.1.

Comment: What about the indexed content in search engines?

Comment: @FrankGroot, they no longer reference the page. It will always throw a 404. It will take time and crawlers will update the new links. How long would it take? I have no idea.

Comment: @M.Joraid And that is not the way to go, because you will lose history in the search machines. So you have to write 301 rewrite rules for those links, otherwise you will get penalized by the search engines :)

Comment: if you "Remove var folder" wouldn't that also remove `.htaccess` which would be bad?