# Magento 2 is generating the product url with catalog/product/view/id instead of product name

Tags: magento2, url, url-rewrite, product-urls

We are having a strange problem in our Magento 2 webshop. Our webshop has different ways of generating the product url. So some of our products just show the product url as it should be **/name-of-the-product** and others show it with the following structure:

`domain.com/catalog/product/view/id/2221/name-of-the-product`

And then we have a third way and that is that it includes the **category id** in the url like:

```
domain.com/catalog/product/view/id/5856/s/name-of-the-product/category/899
```

We would all products like to be just with the name of the product so:

```
domain.com/name-of-the-product
```

We tried setting up the search engine optimization settings by configuration / catalog / catalog as shown in the first answer and shown in the image blow, but this did not work:

[image]

We also tried setting up the search engine settings by configuration / general / web / Search engine optimization as shown in the printscreen below, but this also does not work.

[image]

You can see what is happening on https://www.loungeset.nl/accessoires/tuinmeubelhoes. If you scroll a bit down to for instance to AeroCover bbq hoes ø52cm - antraciet you see what is happening

Has anyone a idea how this comes?

Comment: @KingshukDeb the question is about Magento 2.x, not Magento 1.x, so there is no url_rewrite index anymore and the table is now called `url_rewrite`.

Comment: @MichaelPoppinger you are right.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else has this issue, I had the same and the above didn't work for me either. The issue is caused by duplicate url keys being generated from products with the same name. I used this module https://www.cadence-labs.com/2017/11/magento-2-fix-duplicate-url-key-for-categories-and-products/ to change all of the duplicate url keys and then ran the olegkoval regenerate url rewrites module afterwards and this fixed the issue.

Hope this helps someone else who is facing the same problem!

Comment: The duplicate URL keys problem has solved it for a few 2.2.x installations I work with. Not dangerous to run the extension even if there are no duplicates, just give it a go!

Comment: i run this nightly with cron and it does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the url rewrite via store configuration:

To enable Url rewrites
Login in to the admin panel,

1. on the side bar click stores.
2. Choose configuration. On left panel
3. expand General and select Web from the list.

The configuration window will open, click on Search Engine Optimization and look for "**Use Web Server Rewrites**" and Set it to yes. Also run below listed commands from your root directory in command prompt after this settings:

- **php bin/magento cache:flush**

and

- **php bin/magento indexer:reindex**

Also verify if .htaccess file is available at your root directory and **mod_rewrite** is enable on your server.

Comment: Hi Himmat, thank you for your reply and we have this enabled, I will put a printscreen in the question, so this does not look to help. See my question to see the settings, any other ideas?

Comment: Please see my updated post now and let me know if it helps.. Don't forget to flush configuration cache and run indexer:reindex command after doing that..

Comment: thanks for your quick reply and also tried that one, both settings were already setup correctly and now also put that setting in the question so you can see what it has. Are there other settings that I could try?

Comment: Run the commands at your root directory in command prompt. I have updated my post with commands.

Comment: Verify if mod_rewrite is enable on server. You can do that by checking phpinfo of your website.

Comment: We have just run the indexes and mod_rewrite should be enabled, so really strange, we did also do the cache

Comment: O yeah and the htacces is available on the server. I just placed a link in the question so you can also see the page were it is happening

Comment: It seems Url rewrite is working now, isn't it? Just add .html suffix to your urls by following the given thread It will help in website SEO. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115194/magento-2-product-url-suffix

Comment: Unfortunately not yet, if you look for instance to product: AeroCover kussentas 175x80xh60 - antraciet, it is still going wrong. The strange thing is that by some products it is working fine and others is not going good..

Comment: Ok, don't worry, please open your database and  truncate the catalog_url_rewrite_product_category table and re-run the indexer:reindex and flush cache command. Just take backup by exporting this particular table before truncate in case anything wrong occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Use Extensions “Regenerate Url rewrites”

https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites

After install
run below command

bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate

it is working for me.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Please you this module to regenerate products URL...

https://github.com/Iazel/magento2-regenurl

Comment: Can you expand why this is necessary? Readme is quite unclear, is there same code which is used for reindex catalog url? Thanks

Comment: Please note many time magneto doesn't generate URL due to which it take
default URL  (without rewrite) to overcome the issue I uses this extension
and it work for me.

Comment: I tried this module once and some of my products got vanished from the store and database then I had to add them manually. So please take database or products backup before using any module and regenerating products URL's

Answer (score 0):

The URL for that particular product might not exist in the URL Rewrites of Magento, the way I solved the issue was by manually creating a product URL rewrite for each category manually. 
It's a long process my friend, otherwise use an extension.