# Wrong url redirection for product or category page Magento 2.2.3

Tags: url-rewrite, magento2.2.3, redirect-url, catalog-url-rewrite

I am using magento 2.2.3 for my store.I observed that some of my product page url goes wrong url or 404 ex.

if i am try to open this url:

> https://baseurl/good-tee-hoodie-1-lb

then it open like this:

> https://baseurl/catalog/product/view/id/119/s/good-tee-hoodie-1-lb/category/301/

there can be multiple urls which is not working correctly.

what should i do? Any suggestion?

Is there any way where i can regenrate all the product or category urls? Is that good idea?

I have tried this extension (https://github.com/Iazel/magento2-regenurl) to regenerate the url but it's not working for me.

Please help me out with this probelm.

Comment: did you try re-indexing ?

Comment: Hi, I think you can get some solution here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/168120/magento-2-is-generating-the-product-url-with-catalog-product-view-id-instead-of please try once.

Comment: @Pawan: Do you think it will work?

Comment: @Pawan : re-indexing is not working for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For above my problem, I seem to have found my solution for that after too much googling.

I have used below extension which is free.

https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls

for that particular products i have regenerate product urls again.It working for me correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this more for people that run into this issue and are pulling their hair out.

Simple solution for this, no code required.

Go into the product, add a random letter to the end of the product URL Key. UNCHECK the permanent redirect. Save. Remove random character, uncheck redirect, save. 99% of the time the item is fixed.

You are causing Magento to erase what it has in the database and regenerate the URLs.

What's that? Got a bunch to do all at once? No problem. Same thing, but this time do it on the category the items are in.