# Magento 2 .html.html issue after update from Configuration > Catalog

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, product-urls

I am trying to remove the `.html.html` from Products and Categories url.

I have gone procedure with the below steps after some research on this issue.

Stap 1.

```
SELECT * FROM `url_rewrite` WHERE `entity_type` LIKE 'product' AND `target_path` LIKE '%.html.html%' 

//Than delete all the result rows

UPDATE url_rewrite SET request_path = REPLACE(request_path, '.html.html', '.html') where entity_type="product" 


SELECT * FROM `url_rewrite` WHERE `entity_type` LIKE 'category' AND `target_path` LIKE '%.html.html%' 

//Than delete all the result rows

UPDATE url_rewrite SET request_path = REPLACE(request_path, '.html.html', '.html') where entity_type="category"
```

I have tried but when I run `indexer:reindex` the issue is remain same.

After that, I have go to the `Magento 2 Admin -> Catalog -> SEO -> Product URL Suffix` and removed the `.html`from field and Save Config.

I have tried but when I run `cache:flush`. And go to the `Magento 2 Admin -> Products -> Catalog` and select all the products and do `Updated Attributes`. When I go to the `url_rewrite` table and check all the URL has removed the single `.html`.

The issue with the new products when I create new product it's not adding the `.html` suffix, for that I have again go to the `Magento 2 Admin -> Catalog -> SEO -> Product URL Suffix` and added the `.html`in field and Save Config.

After `Save Config` all the products urls added again `.html.html`.

How I can check this issue so that the existing products has single `.html` and when I add new product it will add the `.html` suffix. Or where I can check in this in the Module:

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/
```

Please help me out this issue.

I am still not receive any answer on this question.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115194/magento-2-product-url-suffix

Comment: @AnkitShah I have done this steps many time, if you can see my answer I had done already. The issue with when I add `.html` again for new products.

Comment: 1] Export Products 2] Change URL in CSV & 3] Import It Again.Then do reindex

Comment: @AnkitShah I have done already, but when I edit any existing product this issue will come again.

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-url-rewrite-programmatically.html

Comment: @AnkitShah, where I can Generate constructor file, in the `/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/`? or any other palace? please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After do many research for this question and can't get any success. I have solved this issue to edit the Model file of `/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/` module.

I have overwrite the Catalog URL Rewrite Module model file:

**/app/code/Magento/CatalogUrlRewrite/Model/ProductUrlRewriteGenerator.php**

In this file I have overwirte the below function like below:

```
protected function generateForSpecificStoreView($storeId, $productCategories)
    {
        $categories = [];
        foreach ($productCategories as $category) {
            if ($this->isCategoryProperForGenerating($category, $storeId)) {
                $categories[] = $category;
            }
        }
        $this->productCategories = $this->objectRegistryFactory->create(['entities' => $categories]);
        /**
         * @var $urls \Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite[]
         */
        $urls = array_merge(
            $this->canonicalUrlRewriteGenerator->generate($storeId, $this->product),
            $this->categoriesUrlRewriteGenerator->generate($storeId, $this->product, $this->productCategories),
            $this->currentUrlRewritesRegenerator->generate($storeId, $this->product, $this->productCategories),
            $this->getAnchorUrlRewriteGenerator()->generate($storeId, $this->product, $this->productCategories)
        );

        foreach ($urls as $key => $value) {
             $value->getRequestPath();

             $newURL=str_replace(".html.html", ".html", $value->getRequestPath(),$count);
             if ($count > 0) {
                $value->setRequestPath($newURL);
             }
        } 

        /* Reduce duplicates. Last wins */
        $result = [];
        foreach ($urls as $url) {
            $result[$url->getTargetPath() . '-' . $url->getStoreId()] = $url;
        }
        $this->productCategories = null;
        return $result;
    }
```

And now it's working fine for me.

Comment: @AnkitShah, please look the above answer.

Comment: @mageDev0688 your code gives fatal error:  `Call to private method Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlRewriteGenerator::getAnchorUrlRewriteGenerator() from context`

Comment: @Nirav Which version you using?

Comment: @mageDev0688 i just override your given code in my custom module. the error was generated because `$this->getAnchorUrlRewriteGenerator()->generate($storeId, $this->product, $this->productCategories)` this is a private method. so you cant use private method out of context. i just solved that error in my custom extension :)

Comment: When I add this code and delete the url_rewrite table URL is not regenerated

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due the '.hmtl' entry in 'catalog_product_entity_varchar' for url_path attribute. While importing the products we should omit .html for url_path attribute. As we set product suffix - .html in admin side(Catalog > Search Engine Optimization), the correct url with one .html will be created in url_rewrite table.

If you already import products with '.html' in url_path attribute, please do below steps to correct 2 .html issue.

- UPDATE catalog_product_entity_varchar SET value = REPLACE(value, '.html', '') WHERE attribute_id = 125; // replace correct attribute id for product url_path attribute
- Do reindex
- GO go admin and save main category. This is regenerate url_rewrite for products under this category
- delete from url_rewrite where entity_type = 'product' and redirect_type = 301; // Delete entries which is created for old urls