# How to remove .html from Magento 2catergory url

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am developing an online store using Magento 2. I am using the Sm mega menu. In their nav section in mobile view, they show categories. So I want to create home categories and show them in nav bar hover and redirect it to home page.

Comment: Your question and description is totally different.

Comment: I want to redirect home in catergories redirect with .html example i want to redirect home but it redirect with .html then page didnt load properly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2: Product URL Suffix](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115194/magento-2-product-url-suffix)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Search Engine Optimization >  Category URL Suffix to remove .html you can change configuration and save it.

Comment: But i changed but say "Unique constraint violation found "

Comment: That means you have used same url rewrites for two entities.

Comment: Any idea how can i find that link

Comment: I think you can look into `url_rewrite` table for it.

Comment: Did you create a category with name `home`?

Comment: Yes, i created home catergory

Comment: Ok as you have category `home` and your homepage have same seo-url `home`. This making a problem. You can either change main home page url by updating the page or you can change the category

Comment: I will try but there problem without html some blocks didnt load properly any other way to do this only for home catergory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69889/discussion-between-ruc-and-salma-saiyad).