# Remove .html from category in product URL?

Tags: magento2, url

For some reason, I am getting .html in my product URL, like so: https://example.com/mycategory.html/myproduct.html. I want to remove .html from mycategory when I am on a product page.

Is there a setting for this? I know I can remove .html from the category completely, but this is not what I want, I want it to be there in category pages. Strange thing is, for some products it works, no .html in the category path.

**Magento 2.3.3**

Thanks

Comment: Please refer this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204984/how-to-remove-html-from-magento-2catergory-url/204989

Comment: Wont that remove it from the category URL on the category page itself also?

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
Stores-> Configuration-> Catalog-> Catalog-> 
Search Engine Optimization-> Category URL Suffix
```

to remove .html you can change configuration and save it.

Comment: This will also remove it from the category page URL, which is not what I want.