# Magento rewrite url not adding .html to category

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

when I am trying to add url rewrite for a category, selected **sale** category. it is adding as sale./ but I need sale.html/

how to change this sale./ to sale.html for url category or url product...?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/115215/49821 check this might be helpful to you .

Comment: Actually you don't need to write .html in url-rewrite if you configure like above magento will automatically add it.

Answer (score 0):

you can login as Admin

stores -> settings -> configuration -> catalog -> catalog ->Search Engine Optimization -> change in "product url suffix" and "category url suffix" from **./** to **.html/**

[image: seo url rewrite suffix in magento2]