# Magento 2: I need to remove .html from category url

Tags: magento2

I need to remove .html from category Url.

e.g

```
https://mysite/categoryname.html

Required url:

https://mysite/categoryname
```

I am removing from admin. But it's not working.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: where you have change setting

Comment: Did you try to spend some time on internet to search about it !!

Comment: Go to Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Search Engine Optimization > Category URL Suffix to remove .html you can change configuration and save it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2: Product URL Suffix](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115194/magento-2-product-url-suffix)

Comment: When I try to remove the Catalog URL Suffix I am getting following error:

Unique constraint violation found

Comment: @Shiwani please see my answer again....

Answer (score 4):

Open admin panel and go to  :-

> **Stores >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Search Engine Optimization**

Here Two option

```
Product URL Suffix = .html 

Category URL Suffix= .html
```

Please leave as Blank

Please see screenshots :- https://prnt.sc/nd2owm

If you get this type of error :-

> Unique constraint violation found

**Please Follow this steps one by one.**

1).  Backup your current Magento2 database

2).  Delete all records from table url_rewrite. You can run the following SQL command:  `DELETE FROM url_rewrite WHERE entity_type = 'product';`

3).Login to your Magento 2 backend >> **Re-save all your Categories**
   and then run this command :- `php bin/magento cache:flush`

4).Then you will be able to save the Product URL Suffix in the Configuration Settings.