# Remove the suffix from the url and set the same url for all products

Tags: magento2

> Set the same url key for all products in magento 2.3
>
> Example : www.example.com/test/custom
>
> www.example.com/tested/custom

I want to set the same url for all products.

Can you please help me how to achieve this in magento 2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2: Product URL Suffix](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115194/magento-2-product-url-suffix)

Comment: You mean If I click of any products it redirects one page, right?

Comment: Can you please let me know how to set the same url for all products in magento 2

Example : www.example.com/test/custom

www.example.com/tested/custom