# Redirect .html to none html on URL

Tags: magento-2.1, category, url, url-rewrite, redirect-url

I tried to remove .html from my categories from admin panel and it works. now I have example.com/test , but example.com/test.html is 404 now. how can I redirect all .html urls to non html one?
should I do it from nginx? how?

Comment: do you want to remove .html from the url?

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/115215/85907 and after chnage you reindex and clear cache of your store ???

Comment: I did it before as I described on my question. but redirect is not working, so I get 404 on .html urls if I remove html from url on admin panel

Answer (score 0):

If you have a website with URLs like magepow.com/hello-world.html 1 and if you want to redirect that to magepow.com/hello-world/, then you can try the below code. Copy/paste this into your .htaccess file. Make sure you replace magepow.com 1 with your own URL.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+).html$ http://magepow.com/$1
```

This should work fine, and if your website has ‘HTTPS’ instead of ‘HTTP’, do change that as well.

Note: If the above code is not working for your website, you can try these instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/([^/.]+).html$ /$1/$2/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/.]+).html$ /$1/$2/$3/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/.]+).html$ /$1/$2/$3/$4/
```